# Type of Standard Errors using PLM Package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, standard-error

Suppose I ran the following R code:

```
plm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = df, effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("country", "year"))
```

That is, I have panel data and am using the `plm` package.

Which type of standard errors am I getting from the code above if I do not adjust anything else? Is it

- homoskedastic standard errors,
- heteroskededastic-robust standard errors
- heteroskedastic-robust and clustered standard errors,
- something else?